# How can I run chef-client remotely (windows to windows) without a password

Tags: chef, winrm, knife

I really hope I'm missing something here - because I'm starting to love Chef, but some pieces feel extremely stupid.

I have a process (service) that runs under specific credentials. Those credentials (user / password) were typed in once upon installation of the service and are not visible to humans anymore. I want *that* process to be able to run the following knife command:

```
# Go kick the nodes and tell them to update now.
knife winrm "role:Xyz" "chef-client"
```

I don't want to have the password written down or the user name. I want this to run under my current context, just like if I browsed to a UNC path in explorer `\\ABC\DEF` <-- Windows is 'smart enough' to know who I am and negotiate my credentials.

Another example is when my service connects to SQL Server. I can choose not to include a username/password, but to simply have the credentials of the application passed along.

Surely Chef doesn't require hard coding admin passwords all over the place. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. The short answer is "No", the `knife` utility does not support this. However, `WinRM` *does* natively support the ability to have your credentials come across the wire without having to re-type the username/password!

So, I will have to use the `knife` command to query Chef to find all the nodes in a particular role, but from there, I drop into `powershell` and perform this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TheComputerName -ScriptBlock { chef-client }
```

`knife` does this kinda stuff in parallel, so I'll just have to do that myself in `powershell`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but actually, with the `knife-windows` gem installed you can indeed use `knife winrm` to run commands.

To install the `knife-windows` gem run:

```
gem install knife-windows
```

Then to run Chef-Client on all machines that have the role `xyz` you would simply run:

```
knife winrm 'role:xyz' 'chef-client' --winrm-user $AdminUser --winrm-password $AdminPassword
```

Assuming that `$AdminUser` and `$AdminPassword` variables contains values that has sufficient permission to WinRM to the target machine.

**NOTE (if using ChefDK):**

Depending on your setup you may need to use:

```
chef gem install knife-windows
```

and

```
chef exec knife winrm 'role:xyz' 'chef-client' --winrm-user $AdminUser --winrm-password $AdminPassword
```

Depending on whether you are using the embedded Ruby environment or your own.

Comment: Hi @Belogix, my question is "how can I do this with my current context, and not by writing down my password." In your example, you are providing a user/password.

Comment: @TimothyKhouri Password management is a whole different topic. However, you would normally have your password stored in a secure location (Secret Server or encrpyted data bag that you pull down via a `knife` command etc). Then you would use that password and pass in the call to `knife winrm ...`.

Comment: so, knife winrm command you mentioned is only after bootstrap. Right? what is the command to bootstrap windows client. I tried official webpage, some blogs, but no success